# pushing different ids to array and getting an array if all id's are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add the id's to array if those are available like as below

```
export const extractOpaqueConstructionType = library => {
  const opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds= [];
  opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.push(library?.exteriorWallId);
  opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.push(library?.exteriorFloorId);
  opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.push(library?.roofId);
  opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.push(library?.interiorWallId);
  opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.push(library?.interiorFloorId);
  opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.push(library?.belowGradeWallId);
  opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.push(library?.slabOnGradeId);
  return { opaqueConstructions: opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds || null };
};
```

I am calling above function in other place like as below

```
extractSecondaryIds: library => {
    const secondaryIds = {
      ...extractSourceOfData(library),
      ...extractOpaqueConstructionType(library), // this is where i am calling above function
      ...extractGlazingConstructionType(library)
    };
    return secondaryIds;
  },
```

if all the above id's for example(exteriorWallId, exteriorFloorId, etc...) are undefined, I am getting output from the above function (`extractOpaqueConstructionType`) like `opaqueConstructions: [null]` where as I am expecting like this `opaqueConstructions: null` if id's are undefined

Could any one please suggest any ideas or alternative approaches on this that would be very grateful to me, many thanks in advance.

Comment: could any one please suggest any thing wrong with the above code

Comment: `opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds || null` is testing for the truthiness of the array (it always is), not whether any of the elements are non-`undefined`. Write an explicit condition checking for that.

Comment: could you please let me know, how can i fix and i need to check for undefined as well. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array after push all values.

Also you can simplify the code by simple remove the push calls

```js
export const extractOpaqueConstructionType = library => {
  const opaqueConstructions = [
    library?.exteriorWallId,
    library?.exteriorFloorId,
    library?.roofId,
    library?.interiorWallId,
    library?.interiorFloorId,
    library?.belowGradeWallId,
    library?.slabOnGradeId,
  ].filter(it => it !== null);

  return { opaqueConstructions: opaqueConstructions.length ? opaqueConstructions : null };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
export const extractOpaqueConstructionType = library => {
const opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds= [
library?.exteriorWallId
library?.exteriorFloorId,
library?.roofId,
library?.interiorWallId,
library?.interiorFloorId,
library?.belowGradeWallId,
library?.slabOnGradeId,
].filter(keyValue => keyValue!==undefine);

return { opaqueConstructions:opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds.length? 
opaqueConstructionSecondaryIds : null };
};
```

Comment: sorry I cannot use this one, because there are other properties in library that I do not want push to the array

Comment: As @uke suggested, it needs to be filtered. I have filtered against `undefine` value. Refere update snippets.